# Setting custom attributes for Devise model User through registration page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, attributes

I'm trying to allow the user to sign up with a first name and last name using Devise.  I've added first name and last name attributes to the user model, and input fields for each in the `registrations/new.html.erb` page.  But when a user tries to sign up, I keep getting this error:

> ArgumentError in RegistrationsController#create wrong number of
>   arguments (0 for 1)

```
def sign_up_params
    params.require[:user].permit[:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]
end
```

With this underneath it:

```
app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:6:in `sign_up_params'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"W6fWxCPX6LchBYyNnlzQ+TdmBSWtmzy8JeI/jRPJCiY=",
 "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Bill",
 "last_name"=>"Burr",
 "email"=>"billburr@example.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

This is what my Registrations controller looks like:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

private

def sign_up_params
    params.require[:user].permit[:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]
end

def account_update_params
    params.require[:user].permit[:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]
end

end
```

Here is my new registration view:

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <h2>Sign up</h2>

    <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>

      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :first_name, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :last_name, required: true %>
        <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
        <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

I'm not sure exactly where I'm going wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `[]` to `()`:

```
def sign_up_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
end
```

`#require` and `#permit` are method calls.